# How to add fixation cross on grey screen using psychopy?

Tags: measurement

I want to insert the placeholders "welcome text", "instruction text", "fixation cross" and "thank you text" on the grey screen. The black fixation cross appears in the middle of the screen for a duration of 90 seconds. the black cross should randomly "flash" (turn red for 200 ms) ten times during this 90
seconds period. to make sure that random flashes do not occur directly one after the other, there should be an interval of at least two seconds between two flashes.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  You will need some custom code to do this - are you working with Python or Javascript (ie, is this an offline or online experiment)?  Also, for programming questions, you may have more luck on StackOverflow or the PsychoPy Discourse forum.